# Clone a set of data in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table of test questions, and a table of test answers. Each test answer has a question_id field which relates it back to the question. Each question  has a course_id field and a test_type field (which is a 1 or 2 depending on if it's a pre or post test).

I'm trying to make a function in a laravel controller that will duplicate the pre or post test into whichever other test type it is. My code currently looks like this:

```
public function tcopy (Request $request) {
    $courseId = $request->input('data.courseId');
    $copyToTest = $request->input('data.copyToTest');
    $copyFromTest = $request->input('data.copyFromTest');

    // Delete any answers currently in the new test type
    $toTestQuestionsOld = Question::where('course_id', $courseId)
        ->where('test_type', $copyToTest)
        ->delete();

    $fromTestQuestions = Question::where('course_id', $courseId)
        ->where('test_type', $copyFromTest)
        ->get();
```

I'm just not sure what to put after that that would clone the collection (which would consist of both the questions and the related answers). I've looked into $newCollection = clone $oldCollection, but that seems to leave the id fields the same, which would just replace the fromTestQuestions right?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Clarification, what do you mean by "*which would consist of both the questions and the related answers*"? Is there an `Answer` model and `answer`/`question` relationship between the two?

Comment: Yes, there's a related Answer model, I'd use something like Answer::where() to get those... which I suppose means I need to delete all the old Answers too. Sorry, should have mentioned that.

Comment: No problem. You can use `Question::with(["answer"])->where(...)->get()` to eager load that. Now, if you want to clone both the questions and answers, you'd have to loop over each question, use the `replicate()` method (which clones the data in the database, including updating ID), then you'd have to `replicate()` the answer and modify it's `question_id` (or reverse if `answer_id` is on `question`), then finally duplicate and modify your `fromTestQuestions` query to use `->where('test_type', $copyToTest)`. Or something similar... There's probably a more efficient approach, but that's an idea.

Comment: Would "answer" be all lowercase or capitalized? The Answer model is capitalized. I should mention that there are multiple answers/question

Comment: `Answer` would be the model, `answer` would be the relationship on your `Question` model: `public function answer(){ return $this->hasOne(Answer::class); }`, as an example. Edit: Ok then, `answers`, and `$this->hasMany()` instead of `hasOne()`